# obtain md5sum on every linked library

Tags: bash, md5sum, ldd

I've got an issue where a program suddenly doesn't want to start, no error, no nothing. To ensure the integrity of the code and its linked libraries I wanted to compare the md5sum of every (dynamically) linked library. From other posts in this forum I found it easy to list all the linked libraries show them nicely:

```
ldd myProgram | grep so | sed -e '/^[^\t]/ d' \
| sed -e 's/\t//' | sed -e 's/.*=..//' \
| sed -e 's/ (0.*)//'
```

How can I add the md5sum or sha1sum so it will add a column with the checksum next to the filename? Simply adding md5sum only produces one line and doesn't seem to do the job:

```
ldd myProgram | grep so | sed -e '/^[^\t]/ d' \
| sed -e 's/\t//' | sed -e 's/.*=..//' \
| sed -e 's/ (0.*)//' | md5sum
```

yields

```
3baf2fafbce4dc8a313ded067c0fccab  -
```

leaving md5sum out produces the nice list of linked libraries:

```
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/i686/cmov/libpthread.so.0
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/i686/cmov/librt.so.1
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/i686/cmov/libdl.so.2
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libz.so.1
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libodbc.so.1
/usr/lib/libcrypto++.so.9
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpng12.so.0
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/i686/cmov/libm.so.6
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/i686/cmov/libc.so.6
/lib/ld-linux.so.2
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libltdl.so.7
```

Any hint is much appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Your script is doing is piping the literal text "/lib/i386-linux-gnu/i686/cmov/libpthread.so.0..." etc. and calculating the md5sum of that...

You can use [xargs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xargs) to repeat any command on every line of input. The -I{} isn't strictly necessary but I'd recommend as makes your script more readable and easier to understand

For example

```
adam@brimstone:~$ ldd $(which bash) 
    | grep so | sed -e '/^[^\t]/ d' 
    | sed -e 's/\t//' | sed -e 's/.*=..//' 
    | sed -e 's/ (0.*)//' 
    | xargs -I{} md5sum {}

6a0cb513f136f5c40332e3882e603a02  /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtinfo.so.5
c60bb4f3ae0157644b993cc3c0d2d11e  /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2
365459887779aa8a0d3148714d464cc4  /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
578a20e00cb67c5041a78a5e9281b70c  /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
```

Answer (score 0):

For loop can also be used:

```html
for FILE in `<your command>`;do md5sum $FILE;done

For eg:
for FILE in `ldd /usr/bin/gcc | grep so | sed -e '/^[^\t]/ d' | sed -e 's/\t//' | sed -e 's/.*=..//' | sed -e 's/ (0.*)//'`;do md5sum $FILE;done
```

Comment: Does this cope with spaces in filenames?

Comment: I belive none of the share libraries in unix got space in its name. Which file are you talking about? Any way, your original command is wrapped inside for loop. So check your command.

Comment: Just highlighting that "for FILE in" will fail when used with filenames with spaces, e.g. non-default installs, mounted network shares etc.

Comment: @Adam, I was not aware, thanks for that comment, +1.